# Searching for " * " string in a Dataframe Column

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, pandas

I need to find and remove every row where the value of the column "D_E_L_E_T_" is "*", the thing is, when run the code I get every single row as a return. Here is a sample of the code:

`bd.loc[bd['D_E_L_E_T_'] == "*"]`

I'm not sure if this happens because I got this data from a CSV, using the following code:

`bd = pd.read_csv("SD2 BD.csv", encoding="ISO-8859-1", error_bad_lines=False, delimiter=";")`

I know this is happening because * is a wildcard but how can I come around that? looked it up everywhere and couldn't find an answer.

Comment: This is not replicable on my system.  `df.loc[df['a'] == "*"]` gives me exactly the rows with `*` only.

Comment: That's weird, even when I search for * in the excel sarch tool, it shows every single cell. did your data come from a csv file?